# mongodb: Group by and count if a field is not null, else show zero

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have thousands of documents in mongodb which i have to group by groupId and count them if groupId exists and isn't null. If that field has a null value, the result should show 0 in the count. Here are example documents

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e706eb075658f3af3a61694"),
  "name": "child doc 1",
  "email": "abcd@yopmail.com",
  "groupId": ObjectId("5e70708775658f3af3a61695"),
  "createdAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "__v": 0
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e706eb075658f3af3a61694"),
  "name": "child doc 2",
  "email": "abcd@yopmail.com",
  "groupId": ObjectId("5e70708775658f3af3a61695"),
  "createdAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "__v": 0
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e706eb075658f3af3a61694"),
  "name": "child doc 3",
  "email": "abcd@yopmail.com",
  "groupId": ObjectId("5e70708775658f3af3a61695"),
  "createdAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "__v": 0,
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e70708775658f3af3a61695"),
  "name": "parent doc",
  "email": "abcd@yopmail.com",
  "groupId": null,
  "createdAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "__v": 0
}
```

For those documents which don't have groupId null,i.e. the child docs, count should be 0. Also, the result should NOT contain those documents whose groupId is NOT null. Result should be something like,

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e70708775658f3af3a61695"),
  "name": "parent doc",
  "email": "abcd@yopmail.com",
  "groupId": null,
  "createdAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2020-03-17T12:01:12.525+05:30"),
  "count": 3,
  "__v": 0
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a default value for the groupId when is null, this default value must not be the same of other elements that have null groupId.
You could do this using $ifNull https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

And set in the groupId something like id of document. After this you can group elements.
Then you could set zero in count if groupId is the same of id.